# Check if value read from file is a number or string

Tags: lua

I'm reading values from a file. These values could be strings or numbers - I don't know which beforehand - and I'd like to determine the data type after reading. My initial thought was to read in values as a string, cast as a number and then back to a string again and check if this is equal to the original value. For example,

```lua
a = "10.5"

if tostring(tonumber(a)) == a then
  print("It's a number!")
  print(tostring(tonumber(a)))
end

-- It's a number!
-- 10.5
```

This works fine for the given example, but if I change `a = "10.50"` then I run into problems because `tostring(tonumber("10.50"))` becomes `10.5` rather than `10.50`.

I could do some cleaning and remove trailing zeros after reading from file, which is fine and totally doable, and then use the above code, but I wondered if there is an idiomatic way in Lua of checking type of a value that is read in from file?

Comment: Simpler: If `tonumber` returns nil, treat the value as a string.

Comment: @lhf Fantastic! I was totally unaware of that. Much more elegant than my attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if tonumber(a) then
  print("It's a number!")
else
  print("It's not a number!")
end
```

Why do you `print(tostring(tonumber(a)))`?  just `print(a)`

In
`tostring(tonumber("10.50"))`, `tostring` will mess up the formatting. If you want to have a specific formatting use `string.format` instead. If you want to maintain the original formatting just print `a` as is.

Comment: Oh, right. My bad about the print statement. I'm not sure what I was thinking. And so this solution is based on the fact that `tonumber` actually returns whether the casting was successful or not, right? (`nil` or the number itself?)

Comment: in Lua 5.4 tonumber returns either a number (integer or float) or fail which currently is just an alias for nil. please refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-tonumber.